# Why wordpress questions are not part of stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

This is actually some kind of meta-question, but I couldn't find any other dedicated place to submit it, so it's here. 
I am just wondering: 
Why PHP->WD development questions are part of **StackExchange**, while questions in other web domain that are using web frameworks such as Java->Spring or Python->Django are accepted in **Stackoverflow**?

Is there any fundemental difference between them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. PHP and WordPress questions are acceptable on Stackoverflow, any development/code based questions are usually acceptable on Stackoverflow. Here, at the WordPress Stackexchange we primarily deal with questions regarding the WordPress CMS.

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange is a network of many, many communities. Usually each within a specific topic. That does not mean a topic may only fit one community (though it should not be cross-posted but migrated). I can think of many questions that fit [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) and [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). Just like this, there are many questions that fit StackOverflow and WordPres.

Why is there a WordPress StackExchange? Probably because it was proposed in [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), got through the process and graduated. You can read about the full process in their [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> ## Once I propose a site, what happens next?
>
> A site goes through several phases before it launches to the public.
> Each stage is designed to improve the site and build up momentum and
> support.
>
> - Interested parties propose and discuss sample questions to **define** what the site is — and is not — about.
> - Users are asked to **commit** to participate in the site to assure that the site will have enough participation — we don't want to create
>   ghost towns.
> - The site is launched for a **beta period** to seed it with questions, develop the FAQ, appoint temporary moderators, and refine its design.
> - If a site reaches critical mass, it becomes a **full member** of the Stack Exchange Network.
>
> If a proposal loses momentum, it may be re-evaluated or merged with
> similar proposals. Proposals with insufficient activity are subject to
> removal. Deleted proposals can be re-proposed anew by users with
> renewed energy and, hopefully, better resources to bring it to
> commitment.

Comment: OK so from now on,  if I have a development question ragarding wordpress development I'll publish it in Stackoverflow, since I understand that it's OK too

Comment: I can only speak from my own experience and am not a mod on either side, so don't take my work 100%. If your question is WP specific, I'd ask it here, you'll probably get a more WP specific answer

Comment: I have found the better WP answers are given on SO. I've never had one go unanswered.